# How to calculate running total of a measure

Tags: powerbi, measure

I have this measure

```
Average Spend =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table[Spend] ) ) / CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table[Volume] ) )
```

The table has a variable month that the data is grouped by

```
Month  Spend   Customers  var_x   var_y
1      100       10        A       C
2      300       10        A       B
3      500       10        A       C
```

I want to have a graph showing running total spend per customer, so x axis would be month and y axis would be average_spend

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain vanilla:

Go to **Quick Measure**, select **Running total** and pull in your measure and the Month column. That's it.

[image]

The result will look like this:

[image]

And here's the expression that Power BI created for you:

```
Average Spend running total in Month = 
CALCULATE(
    [Average Spend],
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Table'[Month]),
        ISONORAFTER('Table'[Month], MAX('Table'[Month]), DESC)
    )
)
```

Comment: So let's say my number of customers is always 10 and I want to work out a cumulative spend per customer. So month 1 it would be 10, month 2 it would be (10+30)= 40 and month 3 it would be (10+30+50)=90. How can I get it without having to create a measure like number_of_customers

Comment: Also, what happens if i use this function without max?